# How do I run a command using libertine-container-manager exec

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-touch, unity8, libertine

I can see in the documentation for libertine-container-manager (that's `libertine-container-manager -- help`) That the exec option should be able to execute an arbitrary command.

I can't however get it to do anything other than spew python warnings at me ( Can't convert NoneType to str ). I have tried the following:

```
libertine-container-manager exec setxkb dk dvorak
libertine-container-manager exec "setxkb dk dvorak"
libertine-container-manager exec="setxkb dk dvorak"
echo "setxkb dk dvorak" | libertine-container-manager exec
```

None of these gave the desired result (or anything not resulting in an error really)

I'm on Ubuntu touch on an M10 that is not remounted rw.

Comment: `exec` is undocumented because it is meant as a non-user-visible way to run one-off root commands internally. I would recommend using `libertine-launch ` to launch `bash` in your container and then execute the commands you need (see Vladimir's answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
libertine-container-manager exec -i container-id -c "setxkb dk dvorak"
```

or any ways `-c "and the command you want to run"`

Comment: That should probably go into the documentation, even if it is just the help file. My next problem now is that setxkb is not installed when running the default setup X(

Comment: The answer is using `localectl set-x11-keymap dk dvorak` However that returns an error. Oh well, using `libertine-container-manager exec -c "bash"` proved useful

Answer (score 2):

[As Larry Price answered in there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831830), the preferable way is to use `libertine-launch my-container somecmd` or `libertine-launch --id my-container somecmd` for modern distro (16.10) instead of `libertine-container-manager exec..`. See [manual for libertine-launch in a Libertine container](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/libertine-launch.1.html). Note, that `libertine-launch..` and `libertine-container-manager exec..` have some difference when binding directories in user environment.