# Access git in libertine container

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-touch, git, libertine

I have created a libertine container and successfully installed x11 apps.

I have also installed git. How can I access this, or other command line applications from the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a similar question which provides the answer [How do I run a command using libertine-container-manager exec](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762741/how-do-i-run-a-command-using-libertine-container-manager-exec)

```
libertine-container-manager exec -c "tool"
```

This works for apps installed in the default puritine container. If you want to use something you have installed in a container you created yourself you need to specify that:

```
libertine-container-manager exec -c "tool" -i your_container
```